# How To Resize Bitmap Without Aspect Ratio in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in bitmap.I know how can i resize or scale bitmap in android.But problem is suppose my image is 100x500 or any height & width.Now i want to resize it in square like 100x100.How it is possible

Kindly help me.

Comment: Are you looking to crop the 100x500 image?  Or simply squish the original aspect ratio (as the question implies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int dstWidth = 100;
int dstHeight = 100;
boolean doFilter = true;
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, dstWidth, dstHeight, doFilter);
```

Answer (score 7):

For this simple case, the most reasonable thing would be to translate your source image down to the middle, and draw your Bitmap again on a new Canvas.  This type of resize is called a [center crop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) in Android. The idea of a center crop is to result in the largest image that fills the entire bounds, and does not change the aspect ratio.

You can implement this yourself, along with other types of resizing and scaling.  Basically, you use a [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) to post your changes, like scaling and moving (translating), and then draw your original Bitmap on a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) that takes the Matrix into account.

Here's a method I adopted from another answer here (can't find the original post to properly give credit):

```
public static Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth)
{
    int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
    int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();
    float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
    float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
    float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);

    //get the resulting size after scaling
    float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
    float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

    //figure out where we should translate to
    float dx = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
    float dy = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, null);
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific if you want additional help. You'll find that here on Stack Overflow, you typically get better quality responses when you provide quality detail about your question and/or problems.

Answer (score 0):

Made a few modifications to the code from wsanville..and it worked for me
Note that I am using the minimum scale (taking what is the least, so that the whole bitmap can be rendered in the screen..if I take max, then it might go beyond the screen

```
        int sourceWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        int sourceHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
        float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;

        float scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);

        //get the resulting size after scaling
        float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
        float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

        //figure out where we should translate to
        float dx = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
        float dy = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

        Matrix defToScreenMatrix = new Matrix();


        defToScreenMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);
        defToScreenMatrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, defToScreenMatrix, false);
```